# Creating a custom primary key in access

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

Is there a way to create a primary key in access based on provided attributes? For example, say I have a school database, with an entity containing a course's code being in the form LL and it's qualification being in the form LLLA. How would I make it so that whenever a new course is entered into this entity, the primary key for that record is the two attributes amended together in the form LL\LLLA? (Eg IT\BTEC, RM\GCSE)

(Just for reference, a composite key is not an option here as this attribute needs to be referenced in another table)

Comment: A PK can only be made of fields belonging to its table. Your question is unclear to me.

Comment: Edited question to be more clear. (I meant making a primary key in access with two other fields in the table)

Comment: This is not how you work with databases. Create a regular PK, e.g. a Autonumber. Use this as foreign key in the other table. Then when you need the combined string, join the tables and concatenate the columns. Don't store calculated values in the database. [Calculated fields belong in queries, not tables.](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html)

Comment: But surely a primary key made from two fields is a composite key?  Or do you mean one of those new fangled calculated fields which just seems wrong as @Andre has linked to.

Comment: And if you need the combination of both columns to be unique, create a UNIQUE index on the two columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a composite primary key and reference it in another table, but I don't recommend it. As you may be anticipating, it will be extra work to propagate both columns to the related table and all joins on both tables will then have to reference both of the columns in the composite key. Access does provide a little help in working with composite keys in the form of cascading updates and deletes, but the overall effort involved in dealing with composite keys probably isn't worth it.

I recommend using an autonumber column as a surrogate primary key and creating a unique index on the columns that represent your natural key.